# UEFI BIOS - which "Specification Version" is implementied in my system?

Tags: uefi, version

The current discussion about Windows 8 and the new SecureBoot feature of UEFI shows that there are big differences between the different UEFI Specification versions.

Therefore, it would be good to know which specification version is implemented in the UEFI firmware of your own system.

**Are there any tools for Windows and/or Linux available that are able to detect or test the specification version of the UEFI firmware system it is running on is compliant with?**

Or is that an information you can only get from the manufacturer of your computer/mainboard?

Comment: Take a look at this question, it might help you http://superuser.com/questions/401447/does-windows-8-consumer-preview-already-support-installation-on-uefi-capable-sys

Comment: Other than that, I think you can only get these specific version information from the manufacturer.

Comment: This would depend on the manufacturer of the motherboard.  Considering the firmware can be updated on some motherboards depending on their features.  I suspect it would be the current UEFI spectification at the time the motherboard was released.

Comment: @ItsNotAboutTheName I'm also looking for my EFI revision/specification of my PC and so for I couldn't find an answer, not even in your hyperlink.

Answer (score 3):

1. Boot into UEFI Shell (Secure Boot will need to be off if you do not have an Internal Shell).  See [How do I "Boot to UEFI shell"?](https://superuser.com/questions/1057446/how-to-boot-to-uefi-shell/1057594) if needed.
2. Run 'ver':

   Shell> ver
   UEFI Interactive Shell v2.2
   EDK II
   UEFI v2.70 (EDK II, 0x0010000)
   Shell>

For this example, the reported UEFI Specification is v2.70.

Note: UEFI Specification Version is not the same thing as SMBIOS Version or BIOS Version, which can be found in msinfo32.exe.  The original poster (OP) understands this, but I am adding this for others who may not know.